# rsync and vpn tunnel crone execution

Tags: debian, rsync, vpn

I have got webserver which provides my nextcloud and serveral other services. For performance issues I decided to use a raid 0 with several disks. That’s why I urgently need a backup. So I installed a second machine with a more secure und less powerful raidlevel.

Both machines are debianbased. For security reasons the backupmachine is only accessible through an openvpn tunnel. Now I did the first backup from by production server by logging in via ssh to a bash shell. There I established the connection to the other machine by using the openvpn --> configfile command.

That gives me some vpn messages to that shell. So I opened a new shell in a second ssh connection. There I started my rsync command for the folders I want to backup. Everything worked like expected. After finishing the backup I disconnected the second shell, disconnected the vpn tunnel in the first shell and everything was fine.

Now I would like to do that in cronestyle every day. 
My backup.sh looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
openvpn /home/cloud/vpn/tunnel.ovpn
rsync --numeric-ids -avze 'ssh -i /xy' /source/ me@10.8.0.1:/destination
```

Unfortunately this doesn’t  work. I guess the reason is that openvpn blocks the shell, while the tunnel is up. So my questions are:

1. How to make rsync working while the tunnel is up?
2. How to disconnect after the rsync progress has finished? In the manual way I do that by pressing “ESC”.

Answer (score 0):

From what i have read, OpenVPN requires you to put inside username:vpnbook and password:CURENT_PASSWORD, every time you want to connect. To automate the process of connection, you have to create a file and name it "auth.txt" and that file should contain only two lines: username and password. Have you created your **auth** file yet?

When OpenVPN gets its auth.txt (auth.txt is what the file is called in Windows, look for OpenVPN manual and Google for instructions how to create one for Linux) it should be able to connect all on it's own just by mentioning for example **openvpn --config vpnbook-ca1-tcp443.ovpn** in any terminal including from script.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The tunnel already gets established without any user interaction. I did this with certificates. That’s no problem. My problem is that the rsync command from my last post seems to be blocked, while the tunnel is up. So I guess that the VPN command blocks my shell.

Comment: Just thought of this: Do you perhaps have any of OpenVPN IP addresses blocked/blacklisted in those webservers? To find your OpenVPN IP address, connect OpenVPN and visit [this](https://whoer.net/).

Comment: no, thats not the problem. The tunnel is established well. I can use it within a second shell. My problem is, that I can't establish the connection and do a backup through the tunnel within one script, because the tunnel seems to block the shell.